# How can I implement the player being able to place tiles on a 1d array grid?

Tags: tilemap, rust

Tell me if I need to provide more info.

My tile-based sandbox game needs to allow the Player to place tiles He has collected. But the problem is, I do not know how I can place the tile based on the Player's location on a 1d array, I have tried doing this MRE:

```
let mut player_index: usize = 5000 * 2500; // This is the center of the 5000 x 5000 map on the 1d array, where the player starts
let mut player_index_counter_x: isize = 0;
let mut player_index_counter_y: isize = 0;

let mut ftime: f32 = get_frame_time();
let mut fps: f32 = get_fps() as f32;
let mut speed: f32 = 350.0 * ftime;

loop {
    if player_index_counter_x >= 32 {
        player_index += 1;
        player_index_counter_x = 0;
    }

    if player_index_counter_x <= -32 {
        player_index -= 1;
        player_index_counter_x = 0;
    }

    if is_key_down(KeyCode::Q) {
        layers[player_z - 1][player_index] = '#'; // This places a wooden plank where the player is standing
    }

    if is_key_down(KeyCode::D) {
        player_index_counter_x += speed as isize;
    }
    // And so on..
}
```

But the tile placement by the player is off by hundreds of tiles.

The game uses 32x32 pixel tiles.

Comment: For starters, it looks like you're missing index-updating code for when the player's y value exceeds 32. You also have a slightly strange behaviour if the player moves right just far enough to barely cross into the next tile, then immediately moves left: their index doesn't return to the tile they just left and re-entered until they manage to accumulate a whole -32 worth of progress.

Comment: I did not create the index-updating code for the player's y, because I wanted to see if it worked for the player's x first.

Comment: @DMGregory How would I prevent the strange behavior that you mentioned?

Comment: You've already accepted an answer that explains this.

Comment: Ok, I thought that gotanod's answer only made sure that the player_index was in the proper position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tile width size is 32 pixels, the inner area will be between 0-31

**0..31 0..31 0..31 0..31**

So you change the tile index (player_index) in two situations:

1. player_index_counter_x > 31
2. player_index_counter_x < 0

---

```
if player_index_counter_x > 31 {
    player_index += 1;  // one tile right
    //player_index += player_index_counter_x % 32; // if speed is fast enough to move more than one tile in one frame
    //player_index_counter_x = 0;  // if you move 1 by 1 pixel
    player_index_counter_x = player_index_counter_x - 32;  // because speed could be greater than 1
}

if player_index_counter_x < 0 {
    player_index -= 1;  // one tile left
    //player_index_counter_x = 31;  // if you move 1 by 1 pixel
    player_index_counter_x = 32 + player_index_counter_x;  // because speed could be greater than 1
}
```

For the vertical movement, you need to know the number of the tiles in one row.

```
let nTilesInOneRow = 100;
if player_index_counter_y < 0 {
    player_index -= nTilesInRow;  // going up one full row
    player_index_counter_y = 32 + player_index_counter_y;  // because speed could be greater than 1
}
if player_index_counter_y > 31 {
    player_index += nTilesInRow;  // going down one full row
    player_index_counter_y = player_index_counter_y - 32;  // because speed could be greater than 1
}
```

I suppose that you use (player_index_counter_x, player_index_counter_y) to draw the tile of the player.
In the above code, player_index_counter_x, player_index_counter_y is the center of the player tile. The player is just a point.
If you need the top left corner to draw it, just calculate the top-left position:

```
player_index_counter_topleft_x = player_index_counter_x - player_tile_width/2.0;
player_index_counter_topleft_y = player_index_counter_y - player_tile_height/2.0;
```

**TODO:** you need to add more conditions to check that you do not move beyond the map limits.

**DISCLAIMER** I have never used Rust, review the code/pseudocode.